# Merge groupby df with repeated index df, drop non-matching rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, join, group-by

I want to merge the following `df` with the `series_object` below it (details below them):

df1

```
       wallet       cumulative_rewards  position      position_rewards  position_type
0      0x12345                       0      LUSD      1000              LP Pair
0      0x12345                       0      TOKE      200               LP Token
1      0xabcde                       0    UNI_LP      500               LP
1      0xabcde                       0  SUSHI_LP      0                 LP
1      0xabcde                       0       DAI      100               LP Pair
```

series_object: `grouped_toke_transfers = toke_transfers_df.groupby('from_address')['value'].sum()`. Where the `index` is `from_address`and the values of the `series_object` are the `values`.

```
from_address   value
0x12345        13687137402763990447827
0xabcde        58950104860666120622
0xfghij        3491287228881431880579
0xklmno        1260986666816869789
```

Merged `df` details:

1. Keep the wallets from `df1`(repeated indexes/wallets);
2. Add value from `df2`to each corresponding wallet (same value per wallet should appear on each row for that wallet);
3. Merged `df`should not include wallets from df1 where that wallet does not exist in `df2`.

Bonus:
What I want to do, ultimately, is query the merged table for `value` (from `df2`) based on the `position_type`(from `df1`). how would I go about doing this `grouopby()`?

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
print (df1)
    wallet  cumulative_rewards  position  position_rewards position_type
0  0x12345                   0      LUSD              1000       LP Pair
0  0x12345                   0      TOKE               200      LP Token
1  0xabcde                   0    UNI_LP               500            LP
1  0xabcde                   0  SUSHI_LP                 0            LP
1      eee                   0       DAI               100       LP Pair
```

Map solution - create new column `value` with set missing values by [`Series.where`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.where.html):

```
grouped_toke_transfers = toke_transfers_df.groupby('from_address')['value'].sum()
df1['value'] = df1['wallet'].map(grouped_toke_transfers)
df1['wallet'] = df1['wallet'].mask(df1['value'].isna())

print (df1)
    wallet  cumulative_rewards  position  position_rewards position_type  \
0  0x12345                   0      LUSD              1000       LP Pair   
0  0x12345                   0      TOKE               200      LP Token   
1  0xabcde                   0    UNI_LP               500            LP   
1  0xabcde                   0  SUSHI_LP                 0            LP   
1      NaN                   0       DAI               100       LP Pair   

                     value  
0  13687137402763990447827  
0  13687137402763990447827  
1     58950104860666120622  
1     58950104860666120622  
1                      NaN
```

Comment: Actually, I apologize, I had a mistake in terms of the data tyoe of `df2`. I updated the question to show the actual data type now. It is a `Series`object where the `index` is `from_address`, so `from_address` is not a column. That's why your solution wasn't working for me.

Comment: @LuizScheuer - answer was edited.

Comment: Checking now, thanks!

Comment: What it does now is it is giving me `NaNs` for both the `wallet` and `value` columns (although the index is correct). I'm also checking here if there is anything wrong from my side.